# How do I arrange several figures in a 3d axis with python?

Tags: python

I used the python package called `Plotly` and I have generated several figures saved as `.svg`.

Now I want to arrange these `.svg` figures in a 3d axis like in this figure.
[image: Expected]

(In this figure, 7 figures are arranged.)

I checked `Plotly` but all of their 3d examples seem to require certain data input instead of import figure files.

Also, I checked `matplotlib`, and I found `Polygon plots` looks good but I read its source code and realized that it also doesn't have any arguments allowing me to import figure files.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can do is to analyze the figs pixel by pixel.

```
from PIL import Image
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = input()  # Should be iterable.
img = Image.open("path/file%s.jpg" % name)  # I change the format when I saved the plots.
x = img.size[0]
z = img.size[1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

for name in range(name + 1):
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(z):
            r = hex(img.getpixel((i, j))[0])[2:]
            b = hex(img.getpixel((i, j))[1])[2:]
            g = hex(img.getpixel((i, j))[2])[2:]

            if len(r) == 1:
                r = '0' + r
            if len(b) == 1:
                b = '0' + b
            if len(g) == 1:
                g = '0' + g
            color = '#' + r + b + g
            ax.scatter(i, name * 500, j, c=color) # Here 500 is because the size of my figure is 700*500.
plt.show()
```

By this method, I can generate the figures in a 3d axis, but the speed is super slow, and the figure is reversed.